# Is と necessary after a quoted phrase?

Tags: grammar, syntax, phrases, quotes

Hi all I was wondering  if we want  to treat a quoted phrase as a "noun", is it necessary to put a と particle behind the quoted phrase?

For example:

A) The "received" in "received from Tom"

1. 「トムから頂きます」の「頂きます」, or
2. 「トムから頂きます」との「頂きます」 ?

B) The "tadaki" in "itadakimasu"

1. 「いただきます」の「ただき」, or
2. 「いただきます」との「ただき」 ?

Basically I was trying also just to figure out how should we know whether or not to put a と particle after a quote?

Comment: I'm a little confused with your examples... But if I'm understanding correctly, I think you are mistaking the idea of *quoting something* using と, with "using a quote sign". You obviously do not have to use と *every single time* there is a quote sign. You use と to mark indirect (and therefore quoted) speech. "The 'kan' from 'kanji'" is simply 漢字のかん etc.

Comment: @Dave yea you are you right, I was mistaking it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`と` is used to introduce a subordinate clause, and is close to the English `that`. When to omit them with quotations seems to differ between the two languages. I cannot give you an explanation, but let me just illustrate.

- Complement of quotation verbs

  > He said that he likes apples.
  >   　He said he likes apples.
  >   × He said that "I like apples".
  >   　He said "I like apples".
  >
  > 彼は、自分がりんごが好きだと言った。
  >   × 彼は、自分がりんごが好きだ言った。[In Tokyo dialect]
  >   　彼は、「私はりんごが好きだ」と言った。
  >   × 彼は、「私はりんごが好きだ」言った。[In Tokyo dialect]
- Complement of nouns

  > the fact that he likes apples
  >   　the fact he likes apples
  >   × the fact that "he likes apples"
  >   × the fact "he likes apples"
  >
  > 彼がりんごが好きとのこと
  >   × 彼がりんごが好きのこと
  >    　彼がりんごが好き**な**こと
  >   × 「彼はりんごが好き」とのこと
  >   × 「彼はりんごが好き」なこと
  >   × 「彼はりんごが好き」のこと
- As a noun

  > × the word "he" in that "he likes apples"
  >   　the word "he" in "he likes apples"
  >
  > × 「彼はりんごが好き」との「彼」
  >   　「彼はりんごが好き」の「彼」

Comment: Btw what does the asterisk mean in the sentence: 彼がりんごが好き*な*こと ?

Comment: That's due to a bug. I wanted it to be in bold to make it stand out since this is somehing you don't expect from other parts of the paradigm.

Comment: Oic, btw just to confirm, is it that 「いただきます」の「た」と「き」 means "The 'ta' and 'ki' in 'itadakimasu'." ?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes it does.

Comment: ok cool =D just a quick last question, what about if we were to remove the 「 and 」, e.g. 漢字の漢

Comment: @Pacerier That is also possible. It is just a counterpart of not using italics or quotation marks in English: Kan in kanji.

Comment: ok thx for all the help =)